# Angular2 update field and sum + 1 (save to firebase)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I´m trying to update a field on my firebase. I´d like to sum 1 to the field and save on firebase

See the code:

```
 this.chat1
      .update({
        lastMessage: newMessage,
        timestamp: currentTimestamp,
        unreadMessage: unreadMessage + 1 //HERE. Trying to sum the field + 1
      });
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

use the firebase `transaction` method.

as I know this method is not available with angularfire2, so you will have to extract the reference:

```
this.chat1.$ref
    .ref.transaction(unreadMessage => {
        if (unreadMessages === null) {
            return unreadMessage = 1;
        } else {
            return unreadMessage + 1;
        }
    })
```

read more about saving date as trasncations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)